# Figuring out how one program launches another program on Windows

Tags: debugging, benchmarking, execution

I have a Windows program -- a vendor-provided benchmark utility -- that launches an existing game on my system using a set of launch options. I'd like to figure out what those launch options are. Is there any way to detect how the benchmark utility is launching the game?

More generally, is there some tool I can use to detect when and how one process launches another process on Windows?

Comment: Use the task manager and add the column `command line`

Answer (score 2):

As I was faced with the same problem, I figured out a simple, yet for my needs great solution.
I exchanged the called program with a simple custom-written c-program which prints all passed arguments into a logfile.